# Why it is not possible to set several attributes by one call in twiddle?

Tags: properties, jboss, jboss5.x, twiddle

Why it is not possible to set several attributes by one call in twiddle?

Or it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because that might give the impression that the changes will be done atomically, and twiddle isn't nearly that complicated.

Comment: It is very unconvenient.
I need to call several times in order to set all attributes and only then execute some method.